# How resolve this warning Replace this lambda with a method reference in forEach

Tags: java, sonarqube

In this code, I have this warning:

> Replace this lambda with a method reference.

```
attrs.forEach((key, value) -> {
            attributes.put(key, value);
        }
);
```

I don't know resolve this error, because it's in forEach, in map, I can use `::`, but here, I can't.

Any idea?

Comment: It is not a warning or error, it is a **suggestion**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sonar means to do:

```java
attrs.forEach(attributes::put);
```